# Reading Csv file with filter data type mismatch

Tags: c#, csv, oledb

I have a `list`

```
   public List<string> strImportRequiredFields = new List<string> { "ENTRY/CMD #", "PART #", "REFERENCE 1", "REFERENCE 2", "REFERENCE 3", "DUTY PER" };
```

Now this is my Code

```
  string strFilter = string.Join(" = ' ' OR ", new UploadFields().strImportRequiredFields.Select(x => "[" + x.ToString() + "]").ToArray());
  strFilter += " = ' '";
```

Without filter its running and giving all rows

Filter Value is

"[ENTRY/CMD #] = ' ' OR [PART #] = ' ' OR [REFERENCE 1] = ' ' OR
[REFERENCE 2] = ' ' OR [REFERENCE 3] = ' ' OR [DUTY PER] = ' '"

```
 string xlConn = "";
 string strPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadPath"];
 xlConn = new UploadFields().returnConnectionForCSV(strPath);
 OleDbConnection oledb_conn = null;
 oledb_conn = new OleDbConnection(xlConn);
 OleDbDataAdapter oledb_ad = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + Path.GetFileName(filename) + "]" + " Where " + strFilter , oledb_conn);
 DataTable dtImport = new DataTable();
 oledb_ad.Fill(dtImport);
```

It throws Error

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

sample of csv Flie is

```
ENTRY/CMD #,ENTRY TYPE,PORT,ENTRY DATE,COUNTRY OF ORIGIN,IMPORT DATE,EXPORTING COUNTRY,IMPORTER #,IMPORTER OF RECORD,TOTAL MPF,HMF,TOTAL ENTERED VALUE,BOX 37,Box 40,CD #,REC'D DATE,USED DATE,REFERENCE 1,REFERENCE 2,REFERENCE 3,REFERENCE 4,REFERENCE 5,REFERENCE 6,REFERENCE 7,REFERENCE 8,DIRECT ID,DUTIABLE,NONDUTIABLE,PART #,ALTERNATE PART #,DESCRIPTION,IMPORT QTY,AVAIL QTY,OTHER QTY,UEV 1,SPECIFIC RATE,HTSUS,LINE #,UEV 2,AD VALOREM RATE,UEV 3,OTHER RATE,UNIT OF MEASURE,BOX 37 CHECK,DUTY PER,DUTY CALCULATION CODE,YIELD,CLAIMED STATUS,Liquidation Date,RECONCILIATION ENTRY #,RECONCILIATION ENTRY DATE,PROTEST #,PROTEST DATE,POST ENTRY ADJUSTMENT DATE,DUTY STATEMENT #,DUTY STATEMENT PAID DATE,WAREHOUSE WITHDRAWAL ENTRY #,WAREHOUSE WITHDRAWAL DATE,ORIGINAL INVOICE CURRENCY VALUE,CURRENCY CODE,Currency CONVERSION RATE,Share Partner Code
55442435982,,1704,,,7/4/2010,,,,25,,10746,528.02,,,7/5/2010,,530250010,6231440010,82042000,,,,,,,,,,,"869/4 SW 8,0 x 65 mm CZ",20,20,,0.73,,8204200000,,,0.09,,,EA.,,0.0657,7,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
55442435982,,1704,,,7/4/2010,,,,25,,10746,528.02,,,7/5/2010,,530250020,6231440020,82042000,,,,,,,,,05060401002,,"869/4 SW 6,0 x 50 mm CZ",20,20,,0.63,,8204200000,,,0.09,,,EA.,,0.0567,7,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
55442435982,,1704,,,7/4/2010,,,,25,,10746,528.02,,,7/5/2010,,,6231440030,82042000,,,,,,,,,05060421002,,"869/4 M SW 6,0 x 50 mm CZ",20,20,,0.73,,8204200000,,,0.09,,,EA.,,,7,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Same code is working for Xlsx

Any suggestion

Thank You

Comment: Is it because of the formatting of certain columns in excel is different when converting to csv?

Comment: I am not converting, I am just reading csv file with some filter

Answer (score 0):

Criteria Mismatch Usually means that the data you are trying to put into the database or query on can't be accepted because the database is expecting a different type of data. In your case your query needs to match each field type

Comment: Its the general meaning dear, here same code is working for excel, and its retrieving not putting in the database